# Debian installer armhf don't know connect to internet in termux with qemu-system-arm

Tags: debian

I am emulating the debian 11 armhf installer in termux with qemu-system-arm with the initrd and vmlinuz of the installer, but it does not connect to the internet it tells me that the mirror is wrong and yet I tried the x86_64 version with qemu-system-x86_64 in termux and if it connects well to the internet please help me.

The command i use is this:

```
qemu-system-arm -M virt -m 1000M -kernel vmlinuz -initrd initrd.gz -append "console=ttyAMA0"  -netdev user,id=n1,hostfwd=tcp::2222-:22 -device virtio-net-device,netdev=n1 -drive if=pflash,format=raw,read-only=on,file=$PREFIX/share/qemu/edk2-arm-code.fd -nographic
```

Answer (score -2):

I solved it by entering the shell (go back option on calamares) then

- `nano /etc/resolv.conf`
- change to 1.1.1.1
- save
- type exit and install normally

Comment: Some things: 1) Are the changes made on the VM? 2) Change _what_ to `1.1.1.1`? 3) Typing `exit` is not how you exit `nano`. 4) Install what normally?  5) "Normally" means what?

Comment: 1= start debian installer 2= error mirror 3=press go back 4=press "enter shell" 5=type command nano, no vim or vi "nano /etc/resolv.conf" 6=change ip to 1.1.1.1 7=save and exit 8= type command exit, you go back to installer 9=continue installation

Comment: if you run live distro or have installed distro, step 5 can help

Comment: If you want to clarify your answer, please do so by editing the answer.